# Meteor: inject html into client-side file on startup

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, inject, meteor-blaze

Using the [SSR](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr) and [inject initial](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-inject-initial) packages,
I currently have the following **server-side** code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  .....

  Inject.rawHead('importList', function(imports) {
    return imports = Blaze.toHTML(Template.imports);
  });
});
```

This injects a list of html imports into the head, and works perfectly.

I'd like to modify the function so that the code is injected into `/client/imports.html` instead of into the head... can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Looks close to [this solution](http://frozeman.de/blog/2015/01/meteor-platform-packages-and-loading-screens/). Try this in the `client` folder of Meteor or use `if(Meteor.isClient)` for compactness:

```
Inject.rawHead('importList', function(imports){
    return imports = Blaze.toHTML(Template.imports)
})

Meteor.startup(function(){
    //...
})
```